# Proper use of parameters in FirebirdSql

Tags: c#-4.0, firebird

I wonder if anyone can help with the following.

```
using (FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FbCommand command1 = new FbCommand("SELECT @AN_INT FROM RDB$DATABASE", conn);
    command1.Parameters.Add("AN_INT", FbDbType.Integer);
    try
    {
        command1.Prepare();  //  Message=Dynamic SQL Error
                            //SQL error code = -804
                            //Data type unknown
                            //  Source=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
                            //  ErrorCode=335544569
                            //  SQLSTATE=42000
    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FbCommand command2 = new FbCommand("SELECT 123 FROM RDB$DATABASE WHERE 789 >= @AN_INT", conn);
    command2.Parameters.Add("AN_INT", FbDbType.Integer);
    try
    {
        command2.Prepare();  // No Problem
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
    }
}
```

My problem is this - I have picked up a project from another coder and I think that, if possible, I should change the database component to use parameterised queries; the existing technique is to inject values into Sql strings.  The task is to refactor a class  to work in an existing project.

The code sample above demonstrates one problem that I must resolve and I wonder of there are others.  The issue is, essentially, to create a class that will turn strings into parameterised queries.  Has anyone done this, and what traps or tricks might there be along the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query needs to be `SELECT cast(@AN_INT as int) FROM RDB$DATABASE`. Else Firebird doesn't know what the parameter type is (even if it's specified in C# code).

You can try to run this piece of code directly in Firebird to see the limitation of engine itself.

```
execute block
as
begin
    execute statement ('select :foobar from rdb$database')(foobar := 10);
end
```

Comment: That doesnt help me: I cannot guarantee what the sql will be because it is passed to my component from elsewhere.  Notice that in the second query I have no CAST() but firebird has no issue with it.  The old component would have generated a query of the second form, but I need something of the first form.

Comment: are you able to assist me with the 3 questions I posed at the end of the original question?

Comment: In the second query Firebird is able to derive the type from the comparison with `789`. In your first query Firebird doesn't know the type, so they query cannot be prepared, this is a limitation in the query parser of Firebird.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - thanks, but this is a restatement of the problem I am facing.  Perhaps I should put it another way - How might I turn the string 'SELECT :AN_INT FROM RDB$DATABASE' into a parameterised query?  I guess the answer is to transform it into 'SELECT CAST(@AN_INT AS INTEGER) FROM RDB$DATABASE'.  I wonder how straightforward that is going to be - remember the new class needs to be able to handle ANY valid Sql.  I was hoping cincura might be able to comment on the handling of stored procedures.

Comment: It already is a parameterised query, you are just running into a limitation of Firebird with regard to parameters. Maybe it would be better to state the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Ok I have been too sparing with the description - the project I am working on has a class called 'Query'.  The class has a string property 'Sql'.  This will be in the form "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = :AN_ID".  Next, a method of the class 'SetParam()' changes the Sql string to "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 999" - This new Sql is passed to an FBCommand and executed or opened.  It is obvious to me that this class needs refactoring with extreme prejudice, BUT there are some gotchas: that the Firebird driver seems to be quite happy to parse an Sql with NO parameters but barfs when given them

Comment: and no - its NOT a parameterised query its a string - that is the issue.  I really sound snotty but dont mean to be - just lack of space

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - can you confirm that this is a limitation of Firebird and not just the driver/client btw ?  It is surprising to me but both you and Cincura have said so.

Comment: It's a limitation of Firebird itself. 

In fact you can try the same using `EXECUTE STATEMENT` in PSQL directly - see my updated reply.

Comment: @cintura.net ok thanks - what about stored procedure parameters - do they still need to be ordered correctly or can they just be named ?

Comment: That's probably better for another question. Anyway look at http://blog.cincura.net/227021-firebird-net-provider-and-calling-stored-procedures-with-parameters/ .

Comment: Yes I saw that, but the post was very old.  I am going to take the approach that sorting the parameters is harmless and safer.