# Firebird's execute statement with bigint named input parameter

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
execute block
as
declare var_mask bigint;
declare var_dummy int;
begin
    var_mask = bin_shl(1, (64 - 1));

    execute statement ('
select first 1 null
from rdb$database
where bin_and(cast(0 as bigint), :var_mask) <> cast(0 as bigint)
    ')
    (var_mask := var_mask)
    into :var_dummy
    ;
end
```

This one gives nice `arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation.
numeric value is out of range.`.

To make it work I have to do explicit cast of the variable:

```
execute block
as
declare var_mask bigint;
declare var_dummy int;
begin
    var_mask = bin_shl(1, (64 - 1));

    execute statement ('
select first 1 null
from rdb$database
where bin_and(cast(0 as bigint), cast(:var_mask as bigint)) <> cast(0 as bigint)
    ')
    (var_mask := var_mask)
    into :var_dummy
    ;
end
```

Does anybody know why? The type information should carry, isn't it?

Comment: Firebird infers parameter type from the [structure of the query itself](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-sqlnull.html#langrefupd25-sqlnull-rationale), not from the type of the variable bound nor (what would amount to the same thing) the surrounding language's understanding of variables.  Some consider this a [limitation of the engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451797/132382).

Comment: Dammit. I actually answered there my question. :)

Comment: Ha.  I've earned the "amnesiac" badge a few times, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Adriano's answer the type information actually does not carry - more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451412/proper-use-of-parameters-in-firebirdsql/11451797#11451797), from me actually :).

Answer (score 3):

Because BIN_AND describes the second parameter as INTEGER, even when you pass a BIGINT to the first one. Whether this is good or bad is subject to discussion.

Comment: "cast(:var_mask as bigint)" makes the described parameter as BIGINT. It's like the old trick of "CAST(? AS SOMETHING)" in the client, that if not given, would throw a "Data type error".